# Does 「密度」have any special meaning in context of computers?

Tags: meaning, computing

I was reading [this](https://qiita.com/MahoTakara/items/85096f8b2632c802ab22) article and came across the line below

> **資源の稼働率**： 高い効率と密度

Here's how I understood it

Availability Factor of Resources: Highly efficient and dense.

But I think I am missing something. Availability Factor here hints more at efficient usage of resources like the succeeding line after colon indicates but I couldn't figure out what "dense" exactly means in this context. Does it mean a high value of availability factor (which is a good thing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

稼働率 is often synonymous with availability (可用性), but in this context it refers to the resource (CPU/memory) usage rate, i.e., how busy each container is. This line is saying Kubernetes allows you to free idle resources promptly and keep all containers busy enough, thus achieving an effective and "(energetically) dense" system.

Comment: Thank you! Is "dense" a common term to use in this scenario? I couldn't find "dense" used in this kind of context anywhere else. It just feels a like little convoluted usage of the word.

Comment: @vadasambar It's not very common, but I instantly understood it was about autoscaling, so I wouldn't say it's unnatural.

Comment: The same list appears in the Kubernetes documentation in English and the line in question is "high efficiency and density". https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/what-is-kubernetes/